# Why the CustomIOS7AlertView did not show after using UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios

I am developing in iOS for WIFI IP Camera. The APP can connect to the WIFI IP Camera via WiFi.

I can get the all file list which on the IP Camera , it also and download the file from WIFI IP Camera.

So I have two file list. One is the File list on WIFI IP Camera , another is the file list which download from the WIFI IP Camera.

I using **`CustomIOS7AlertView`** to **view the file which on the WIFI IP Camera via WIFI** like the following code.

```
    UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

    UIView *demoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 200)];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 270, 180)];

    [imageView setImage:urlImage];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [demoView addSubview:imageView];

     // Here we need to pass a full frame
    CustomIOS7AlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init];

    // Add some custom content to the alert view
    [alertView setContainerView:demoView];

    // Modify the parameters
    [alertView setButtonTitles:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"OK", nil]];

    [alertView setDelegate:self];

    // You may use a Block, rather than a delegate.
    [alertView setOnButtonTouchUpInside:^(CustomIOS7AlertView *alertView, int buttonIndex) {

         for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems){
              [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
         }

                                    [alertView close];
}];

    [alertView setUseMotionEffects:true];
```

And using the following code to **view the local file which download from the WIFI IP Camera**.

```
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath] ;
documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
[documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

[documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES] ;
```

First time when I view the file which on the WIFI IP Camera , the **`CustomIOS7AlertView`** is work fine.

But the **`CustomIOS7AlertView`** did not show when I want to view the file which on the WIFI IP Camera after I view the local file via `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

It seems the **`CustomIOS7AlertView`** is hidden after using `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is `UIDocumentInteractionController` may leave an additional `window` that we don't need after you used `UIDocumentInteractionController`, when you call `CustomIOS7AlertView` again, it maybe added to the wrong window, and we can't see the AlertView.

Here is my solution:
Make sure your `CustomIOS7AlertView` in *showingViewMethod* before add to window  has the top most window check like this code:

```
NSEnumerator *frontToBackWindows = [UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows reverseObjectEnumerator];

for (UIWindow *window in frontToBackWindows){
    BOOL windowOnMainScreen = window.screen == UIScreen.mainScreen;
    BOOL windowIsVisible = !window.hidden && window.alpha > 0;
    BOOL windowLevelNormal = window.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal;

    if (windowOnMainScreen && windowIsVisible && windowLevelNormal) {
        if(!self.superview){
            //assume self is CustomIOS7AlertView or it's subView will be added to window
            [window addSubview:self];
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Hi @Tom , In `for (UIWindow *window in frontToBackWindows)`. it will run for twice. But after using `UIDocumentInteractionController` , the for loop will run for three times. It seems the `UIDocumentInteractionController` add the additional window like what you say.

Comment: Yes, there are more window, so we have to check    Which window will be use before add alertview

Comment: Does there other method to close the window which create by UIDocumentInteractionController ?